# How to initialize skobbler map object for android?

Tags: android, android-studio, skmaps

What should be the parameters to the SKMapsInitSettings used for initialising the Skobbler map on android? I am using Android Studio and looking for just a basic configuration to get the map up.

I've followed the steps mentioned in this [link](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec002).

Now for the SKMapsInitSettings, I need to pass the location of the assets folder path it seems, this part is not clear from the documentation.

Comment: What work have you done? What does the Constructor look like? What kind of example code have you found? What part of the Documentation is unclear? So much questions...

Comment: I've followed the steps mentioned in the [link](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec002). Now for the  SKMapsInitSettings, I need to pass the location of the assets folder path it seems, this part is not clear from the documentation.

Comment: Please also check the demo projects - they contain runnable examples (currently the demo projects only compile with Android Studio 1.x - we'll soon roll out the Android Studio 2.x support) - http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download